# Return data from an axios get request

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios

Trying to use the below response interface for data sent back by my server. Only problem is response.data.data is apparently blank. However, response.data contains the actual data.

When I hover over the last data in response.data.data it shows it's type as: (Property) ProductResponse.data: ProductDTO.

If I modify my axios.get<>() to return a Product with response.data passed to the constructor everything works fine. But I keep running across this interface pattern being used, so I'm trying to use it myself.

Probably a quick one for the experts, thanks!

```
import axios from "axios";
import Product, { ProductDTO } from "@/models/Product";

interface ProductResponse {
  status: number;
  message: string;
  data: ProductDTO;
}

// Rework to a more generic API
export abstract class ProductApi {
  private static productAxios = axios.create();

  static async getProduct(id: number): Promise<Product> {
    let response = await this.productAxios.get<ProductResponse>(
      "http://localhost:8080/api/product/" + id
    );
    console.log(response.data.data);
    return new Product(response.data.data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your problem might be on the API side, check the way `/api/product/` returns data.

Comment: It returns what I'm expecting. If I switch to just returning <Product> and use response.data everything works as expected. Seems that response.data.data is ending up undefined for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you check the types of the Axios `get()` function, you'll see that it has this implementation:

```
  get<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<R>;
```

https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/index.d.ts#L137

So the first type passed (`T`) is the type of the data, not the type of the response. In your case, you'll have to implement it this way:

```
this.productAxios.get<Product, ProductResponse>
```

Your data is indeed in `response.data` :)